# Updating models in controllers with AJAX Angular JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I am sure this is an easy answer but I am not finding it anywhere.  Essentially I have a `$http` service that brings back a JSON object with a ton of data that I need to use like so:

```
(function (angular) {
    angular.module("forecasting").factory("DataServices", ["$http", function ($http) {
        return {
            //get forecast of entity
            getForecast: function (callback) {
                $http({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: Forecasting.urls.entityAPIRoot + "forecast/1722"
                }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    callback(data);
                }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    callback(data);
                });
            }
        }
    });
} (angular));
```

This is just a service that takes a call back so the data can be saved to the scope like so:

```
DataServices.getForecast(function (data) {
    $scope.forecast = data;
});
```

This works well when trying to show the data in the view, it updates like you think it would.  However simply trying `console.log($scope.forecast)` placed after the above code in my controller does not work.

I want to be able to take subsections of the data so I can use it in my app, however, I can't access `$scope.forecast` so I am not sure how I am able to.

I have looked at other solutions that use `$scope.$apply()` and promises.  I am just kind of lost and not sure where to go from here.

How do I access a subset of the data being saved to the `$scope` outside of the callback?

Comment: Please show how you want to 'use' the data...

Comment: @calebboyd "This works well when trying to show the data in the view, it updates like you think it would. However simply trying console.log($scope.forecast) placed after the above code in my controller does not work." -- part of the original question.

Comment: Your callbacks are executed asynchronously from the code in your controller. I updated my answer with a few ways you can do what you want.

Comment: @calebboyd Cool update.  What would you recommend for doing a lot of processing on the data coming back?  Put it in a service?

Comment: "However simply trying console.log($scope.forecast) placed after the above code in my controller does not work.". Where are you placing the `console.log($scope.forecast)` exactly? are you doing it **after** the  `getForecast()` function or **within** it's body?

Comment: Yeah, you can use the `.then` inside the service, process your data (return it). And `.then` again in your controller (has argument equal to the return value of your `then` in the service. Promises chain, and its fantastic.